# How to use Thread.Sleep with Task.Run without blocking main tread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

Is it possible to make sure that a task runs on another thread than the main thread? So that this piece of code would not bock the calling thread?

```
var task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    //third party code i don't have access to
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
});
```

I know that there is `Task.Delay` but I want to make sure that the task will run on another thread.

Comment: I may be wrong so follow my logic: [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx) "Queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool", I *assume* this is [The Managed Thread Pool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y(v=vs.110).aspx), which says: "Thread pool threads are background threads". Therefore, all `Task.Run` calls will spawn the thread on a background thread. I assume the `Main` thread is always a foreground thread, if so `Task.Run` will never be on the Main thread. Check with `Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground`.

Comment: thanks for the info, i will investigate on it. i was assuming that the task may or may not run on another thread, depending on what the task scheduler thinks is right. so i was looking for a was to make sure that it is another thread. but if you are right, then this is always the case.

Comment: The only way it could run on the main thread is if you wait for it from the main thread before it has started executing (via [task inlining](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2009/10/15/task-wait-and-inlining/)). Other than that, it will execute on the thread pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Nico is correct in that ideally, you could use asynchronous programming all the way. That approach is ideal because it doesn't waste a thread sleeping (or, in a more realistic example, blocking on I/O).

> Is it possible to make sure that a task runs on another thread than the main thread?

Yes. `Task.Run` will always queue work to the thread pool, and the main (entry point) thread is never a thread pool thread.

Answer (score 11):

I think that there are different ways to accomplish what you are trying. But based on what you are trying to do, I think that you would be fine just using async/await which is not going to block your UI for sure, and will allow you to control your task asynchronously.

As MSDN says:

> Async methods are intended to be non-blocking operations. An await
>   expression in an async method doesn’t block the current thread while
>   the awaited task is running. Instead, the expression signs up the rest
>   of the method as a continuation and returns control to the caller of
>   the async method. The async and await keywords don't cause additional
>   threads to be created. Async methods don't require multithreading
>   because an async method doesn't run on its own thread. The method runs
>   on the current synchronization context and uses time on the thread
>   only when the method is active. You can use Task.Run to move CPU-bound
>   work to a background thread, but a background thread doesn't help with
>   a process that's just waiting for results to become available.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx

This is an example of usage:

```
public async Task MyMethodAsync()
{
    Task<int> runTask = RunOperationAsync();

    int result = await longRunningTask;

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

public async Task<int> RunOperationAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000); //1 seconds delay
    return 1;
}
```

This won´t block your UI

Comment: thanks, for the example, but i do not want to use Task.Delay, that is the point of the whole question. how would it work with Thread.Sleep?

Comment: @thalm in this case using async/await Task.Delay has the same usage of Thread.Sleep but that would not block your main thread. Take a look at this Jon Skeet answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13430126/637840

Comment: the problem is that the Thread.Sleep is in user generated code i don't have access to. i can't change it to Task.Delay...

Comment: well ok, that´s another scenario. This, in my opinion, the best way to handle that if you control all the code. If you don´t have access to the 'user generated code', then you probably be better using ThreadPool or BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 0):

Use the thread pool.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => { Thread.Sleep(5000); Console.WriteLine("Threadpool task done."); });
        for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main thread: {0}", i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The output should look like this:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Your current code should work, but you will need to call the `Start()` method on the task to invoke it.

You could also accomplish this through threading:

```
new System.Threading.Thread(() => {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
}).Start();
```

Comment: Creating threads should be avoided as much as possible, since reusing the ones that have already been created is **way** more cheap than creating a new one. Take a look at [Why so much difference in performance between Thread and Task?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125105/why-so-much-difference-in-performance-between-thread-and-task)